# I'm having trouble understanding this expression: $C=\{2m \in \mathbb{Z}: m=1,\ldots,5\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

Does this mean that i must pick a number between 1 and 5 and double its value? ex: $m=4$, $2 \cdot 4=8$, $C=8$

Comment: I would read that as saying that $C$ was the set consisting of $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$.

Comment: Have you read about set builder notation, such as in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#More_complex_expressions_on_the_left_side_of_the_notation

Comment: In the future, please make sure to include a complete question in the *body* of your post, not just the title, which may be abbreviated or otherwise paraphrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to write where you encountered it.

Either way, $C$ will be the set of all integers of the form $2m$ with $1\leq m \leq 5$. Therefore, $C=\{2,4,6,8,10\}$.